# Increasing efficiency of loop that uses datenum function?

Tags: matlab, octave

The following loop takes about 700 seconds to run in octave and 22 seconds to run in matlab when the DJI matrix has 21000 rows. How can I increase the efficiency of this?

```
for i=1:length(DJI)
DJI2(i,1)=datenum(char(DJI(i,2)),'yyyy-mm-dd');
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remember to preallocate DJI2?

More importantly, you do not need the loop at all.  `datenum` operates on arrays.
Try this:

```
DJI2=datenum(char(DJI(:,2)),'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Comment: Using char() does not seem to allow me to call datenum on the entire array, the code example you gave doesn't work.

Comment: What is the type of DJI?  Is it a cell array? If you have an array A = ['2005-10-10'; '2006-11-12'; ...] then datenum(A, 'yyyy-mm-dd') will work.  See if you can convert DJI to something that looks like A.

Answer (score 2):

I replaced the loop with the following and got at least a one order of magnitude increase in speed.

```
DJI2(:,1) = reshape(datenum(strvcat(DJI(:,2)(:)), length(DJI(:,2)),'yyyy-mm-dd'));
```